# php header redirect not echoing text before redirect

Tags: php, header

why is my code not showing/printing "redirecting now ...." text before it redirects.keep in mind that I don't want to use javascript or http_redirect() to redirect.The later will break the flow of my logic.

```
<?php
ob_start();

echo "redirecting now ....";
 sleep(3);    
    header("Location:index.html");
    exit();


ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead

```
<?php
ob_start();

echo "redirecting now ....";
header("Refresh: 3; index.php");
exit();

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: it is working now I think there was an error somewhere in my code

Comment: it IS when I test it :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<?php
    echo "redirecting now ....";
    print "<META http-equiv='refresh' content='3;URL=index.html'>";
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: PHP's "header()" sends an HTTP header - these won't be read or processed by the browser after the main response. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/structure-of-an-http-response/

Comment: so in short using the php header function you can't print anything before redirect

Comment: I think this is the best way to redirect page, you can print anything before redirect also you can set the seconds to wait...

Answer (score 1):

That won't work, the reason to use ob_start() in that context (IMO) is if you have unavoidable output before the header that's preventing the header() from working.

The reason it won't work is because ob_start() captures all the output (in this case echo "redirecting now....";) and doesn't spit it out until ob_end_flush(). You've redirected the page using header() before the script reaches ob_end_flush().

Answer (score 1):

you cant output anything before using the header()

HTTP-Headers should be sent before any output from the server.
If you have an output before, the server will output a warning like 'Headers already been sent'